# ggplot: facet_grid but use one factor level as a reference

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I would like to know how to use a single factor level as a reference to plot other factors against. For instance I have the following:

```
set.seed(4)
x <- factor(c('A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B'))
z <- factor(c('a','a','b','b','c','c','d','d'))
y <- runif(8)
df <- data.frame(x,y,z)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=z)) + 
       geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position='dodge')
```

[image: r_plot]

However unlike the above plot I would like to add a facet dimension something like:

```
p+facet_grid(.~z)
```

but unlike what the above code would give, only showing facets for c('a','b','c') levels and plotting each of these against 'd' as a reference with position='dodge'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If allowed, you can do some transformation of your data before you visualize the result. It might be cumbersome, but you can add an additional variable to discriminate the variable z with `c("a", "b", "c")` and with `"d"`. And then place the color and position according to the additional variable while transforming the original `z` variable into a *facet variable*. In this way you separate variables which determine the facets from the variables that determine the color and position.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 <- df %>% mutate(m = ifelse(z == "d", "d", "abc")) %>% 
       mutate(z = ifelse(z == "d", "a,b,c", as.character(z))) %>% 
       mutate(z = strsplit(z, ",")) %>% unnest(z)
p <- ggplot(df1, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=m)) + 
     geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position='dodge') + facet_grid(. ~ z)
```

[image]